# Pass parameter from Shell to docker-compose / docker

Tags: shell, docker, docker-compose, credentials

I am trying to build docker from Shell script using docker-compose file, and would like to pass credential as parameter. (The credential will be used in Dockerfile). For example, from shell file, ${1} and ${2} are username and password, respectively. 
In Dockerfile, if below command shows "username", then I will be happy enough.
For examples below, to make it simple, ${1} = username

```
RUN echo ${test}
```

In Shell script, below command needs to be used since docker-compose.yml should be used. I don't want to store credential in yml file, would like to pass thru shell script.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-el6.yml build --force-rm --pull
docker-compose -f docker-compose-el6.yml up -d --force-recreate
docker-compose -f docker-compose-el6.yml run -T --rm builder-el6 testmain.py
```

I tried below, but no luck. BLANK.

1) add build-arg

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-el6.yml build --build-arg test=username --force-rm --pull
```

Get the following error

```
Services are built once and then tagged as `project_service`,
e.g. `composetest_db`. If you change a service's `Dockerfile` or the
contents of its build directory, you can run `docker-compose build` to rebuild it.

Usage: build [options] [SERVICE...]

Options:
    --force-rm  Always remove intermediate containers.
    --no-cache  Do not use cache when building the image.
    --pull      Always attempt to pull a newer version of the image.
```

2) add environment variable

```
$SUDO test=username docker-compose -f docker-compose-el6.yml up -d --force-recreate
```

3) add environment variable - another way

```
export test=username
$SUDO docker-compose -f docker-compose-el6.yml up -d --force-recreate
```

4) add environment variable - another another way

```
$SUDO docker-compose -f docker-compose-el6.yml run -T -e test=username --rm builder-el6 testmain.py
```

For information, here is docker version info.

```
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 786b29d
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.7.1
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 786b29d
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

Comment: You usually don't want to put credentials like that anywhere near your Dockerfile.  Anyone who has the image can `docker history` and trivially get every `RUN` command back out, or `docker run ... sh` it and inspect the filesystem.

Comment: `pass credential as parameter` Is the credentials needed to run the container or only needed to build it?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for suggestion, but I would like to pass credential into Dockerfile. Are there anyway?

Comment: @KamilCuk Just to build it I guess, I just need to use them in Dockerfile

Comment: If you need to build only, set up a service that exports the data only at build time. Ex. a simple http docker static site with the password, then inside your docker you only `curl http://<some ip>/yourpassword.txt` to fetch the password and be sure not to store it anywhere. There  is [this](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information) but still not widely used. [This](https://runnable.com/docker/rails/managing-secrets-during-docker-builds) looks like a good read. The "Private gems server" would be my way.